# What does 'npm outdated --depth=0 ' mean to do as ask action when seeing differences?

Tags: npm, version

When running the command *npm outdated --depth=0* I see the following:

```
Package                       Current  Wanted      Latest  Location
cordova                         5.4.1   5.4.1       6.0.0  cordova
grunt-angular-templates         0.5.9   0.5.9       1.0.3  grunt-angular-templates
grunt-autoprefixer              0.4.2   0.4.2       3.0.4  grunt-autoprefixer
grunt-bump                      0.3.4   0.3.4       0.7.0  grunt-bump
...
```

What does those differences between 'Current', 'Wanted' and 'Latest' mean to me? Respectively what am I supposed to do in case?

Answer (score 0):

**Current**: Current version of the packages installed.

**Wanted**: The maximum version of the package that satisfies the semver range specified in package.json. If there's no available semver range (i.e. you're running npm outdated --global, or the package isn't included in package.json), then wanted shows the currently-installed version.

**Latest**: The version of the package tagged as latest in the registry. Running npm publish with no special configuration will publish the package with a dist-tag of latest. This may or may not be the maximum version of the package, or the most-recently published version of the package, depending on how the package's developer manages the latest dist-tag.

Reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated